# Broken package can't be removed without installing it, which I can't do

Tags: apt, package-management, chromebook, storage

I have a problem with my system.  I want to get rid of some packages to free  up some space, because I am running an Ubuntu chroot with crouton on a Chromebook with only 64GB of storage, almost all of which is filled.

However, I have a broken package on my system that is only partially installed.  This is bad, because whenever I try to remove other packages, with the intent to free disk space, APT tries to fully install the package on my system, which isn't possible.

How can I remove this broken package without installing it first?

Comment: Packages tend to be small. There may be easier ways to free up space: Personal files, movies, logfiles, etc.

Comment: Take a look at `man dpkg`, there is a `--force-things`-option. **Warning: use at your own risc, you may brake your system.** Without knowing the package-name and how it came to the incomplete installation it's impossible to give a correct advice.

Comment: The package name is `kicad-packages3d`.  It was incompletely installed because I tried doing `sudo apt upgrade`, but then my computer restarted while it was being upgraded.

Comment: Hmmm. That package's download is about 330 MB, installed size 5GB. How much space do you need to free up to properly install-then-remove the package?

Comment: Okay, wait.  I've lookd at the man page for `dpkg`, and found what looks to be an option to remove a package, even if it is marked for reinstallation.  I think I would go `sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq kicad-packages3d`, right?

Comment: @Blue-ManedHawk I think it's `sudo dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq kicad-packages3d`, you need to specify an action, not only an option.

Comment: Ah. Got it.  I'll try it.

Comment: Hey, @mook765, it worked!

Comment: Please provide an answer, you can mark it as accepted in a few days then, I'll give it an upvote.

Comment: Note that `--force-remove-reinstreq` merely deletes the *database entry*. It does not remove any of the files, which should now be removed...especially if you want to free up space. It also doesn't delete the deb package sitting in /var/cache/apt/archives

Answer (score 1):

I have been through this before with MySQL migration gone bad. I would try this regardless of how much space this is going to save me. I just don't like having broken packages.

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
apt-get purge kicad*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Good luck!